# Calculating $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sec (x)-1}{x^2\sec(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sec (x)-1}{x^2\sec(x)}$$

The first thing to do, as I was taught, was to rewrite this in terms of sine and cosine. Since $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ we have

$$\frac{\frac{1}{\cos(x)}-1}{x^2\frac{1}{\cos(x)}}$$

And that is

$$\frac{\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}}{\frac{x^2}{\cos(x)}}$$

Then

$$\frac{(1-\cos(x))\cdot\cos(x)}{\cos(x) \cdot x^2}$$

And

$$\frac{(1-\cos(x))}{x^2}$$

Alright. It is my understanding that there is a formula or something that states $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} = 0$, so I can apply it here because we actually have

$$\frac{\color{green}{(1-\cos(x))}}{\color{green}{x}\cdot x}$$

Leaving us with

$$\color{green}0\cdot\frac{1}{x}$$

But if we evaluate, we get

$$0\cdot\frac{1}{0}$$

Which I guess is indeterminate because of $\frac{1}{0}$.

Also, the correct answer should be $\frac{1}{2}$.

What was wrong with my procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1-\cos{x} = 2\sin^2{\frac{1}{2}x}$, so
$$ \frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sin{\frac{1}{2}x}}{x/2}\right)^2, $$
and you probably know that
$$ \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin{y}}{y} = 1, $$
so the limit is $1/2$.

Comment: Why is $1-\cos x = 2 \sin^2 \frac{1}{2}x$? Is it some sort of theorem that permits that equivalence?

Comment: The [double angle formula for cosine](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html) can be written in three forms using $\cos^2{a}+\sin^2{a}=1$:
$$ \cos{2a} = \cos^2{a}-\sin^2{a} = 2\cos^2{a}-1 = 1-\sin^2{a}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that you get an undefined form :

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos{(x)}}{x^2}=\frac{0}{0}
$$

So you can use l'Hopital rule to get:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos{(x)}}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{(x)}}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Because as you probably know :

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{(x)}}{x}={(\frac{d}{dx})}_{x=0} {\sin{(x)}}=cos{(0)}=1
$$

You can also use series expansion of $\cos{x}$ near $0$:

$$
\cos{(x)}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^4)
$$

To get:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos{(x)}}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^4)))}{x^2}\\
=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$$
Then
$$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon(x)$$
where $\varepsilon(x)\to 0$ when $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{1+\cos x}\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{1+\cos x}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}  \to \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1^2 = \frac{1}{2}.$$